# Difference between including or not including [:]

Tags: python-3.x

Both declarations produce the same results but I want to know what the difference is behind the scenes.

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a[:] = a[0:3]
print(a)
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = a[0:3]
print(a)
```

Comment: If you have other references to the original list, you can see that they **don't** produce the same results.

Comment: The difference is better understood in terms of Python names. `a = a[0:3]` is basically telling to bind the name `a` to whaterver is on the right-hand side. `a[:] = a[0:3]` access and modifies the underlying memory of the object pointed by `a`. Had this memory been also assigned to a different name, say `b`, accessing the memory from `b` would reflect that change. In the former this would not happen because you are not changing `a`'s memory but `a`s binding.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand it now. So a[:] is modifying the value stored at the object pointed at a, and a = [0:3] does not change the value stored at the object pointed at a but rather create a bounded variable a? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This can be better explained with another variable.

Let's say that a and b are the same. When we use slice assignment, both a and b get changed because they are the same list. Without assigning it to the slice of a means making a new list that is called a that has no relation to b anymore.

```py
a = b = [0, 1, 2]
a[:] = a[0:2]
# a and b point to the same object and that got changed
print(a)  # gives [0, 1]
print(b)  # gives [0, 1]

a = b = [0, 1, 2]
a = a[0:2]
# a and b point to two different objects sharing no memory together
print(a)  # gives [0, 1]
print(b)  # gives [0, 1, 2]
```